# Apache NiFi Controller Start not working with nipyapi client

Tags: apache-nifi, nipyapi

I have been using nipyapi client to manage new Apache NiFi deployments and is working great, but i am getting an issue when trying to ENABLE a Controller Services.

**My Setup:**

I run NiFi in docker and every time a container starts there is a series of steps such as :

- Build NiFi server - OK
- Download the temapltes.xml - OK
- Upload  templates to NiFi - OK
- Deploy templates to NiFi Canvas - OK
- ENABLE Controller Service - **ERROR**

```
import nipyapi
nipyapi.config.nifi_config.host = 'http://localhost:9999/nifi-api'
nipyapi.canvas.get_controller('MariaDB', identifier_type='name', bool_response=False)
#Enable Controler
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = 'http://localhost:9999/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/'+nipyapi.canvas.get_root_pg_id()+'/controller-services'
r = requests.get(url)
reponse = json.loads(r.text)
controllerId = reponse['controllerServices'][0]['id']

nipyapi.canvas.schedule_controller(controllerId, 'True', refresh=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nipyapi/canvas.py", line 1222, in schedule_controller
    assert isinstance(controller, nipyapi.nifi.ControllerServiceEntity)
AssertionError
```

Not sure what i am missing !

**PS** - i have been trying nifi-toolkit but is not working as well

```
 ./cli.sh nifi pg-enable-services --processGroupId 2b8b54ca-016b-1000-0655-c3ec484fd81d -u http://localhost:9999 --verbose
```

Sometimes it works sometimes does not work !

I would like to stick with one tool eg: toolkit or nipyapi (faster)

Any Help would be great ! thx

Comment: There isn't much to go on here... what is the error that happens in nifi? anything in nifi logs? what state does the cs end up in nifi?

Answer (score 3):

Per the error, NiPyAPI expects to be passed the Controller object, not just the ID.

Comment: What would the controller object be ? Is it a Json snippet or what ?

Comment: it's the full json object that the NiFi REST interface returns the canvas.get_controller command.
I could modify this to also accept a UUID for a controller and helpfully retrieve it in a future release - I have opened an Issue to track it. https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi/issues/137